# How to remove delta search from firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Whwnever i open up a new tab in firefox, the page loads a delta search (search engine) page which comprises of various ad's. How can i remove it from firefox. It is not showing up in extensions and addons also.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: This question is off topic for stackoverflow since it isn't about programming, but you may want to [google it](https://www.google.pt/search?client=opera&q=delta+search+removal+firefox)  and you may find some help

Comment: ohhh okzz i didnt knew that.....

Comment: You can delete this question if you want. If you don't, this will eventually be closed

Comment: What happens when this get closed.

Comment: This probably won't get closed since it ins't getting enough attention, but if you managed to solve the problem, you could add an answer and accept it.

Comment: I would have added an answer but my problem isnt solved yet.

Comment: I added an answer with a possible solution. See if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this isn't exactly about programming, here's some things you can try to do to fix it:

From [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/949921)

> **First of all, go to Control panel and uninstall the following apps:**
>
> - Delta
> - Delta Toolbar
> - BrowserProtect
> - Yontoo
>
> **Then, reset the following preferences:**
>
> - browser.newtab.url
> - browser.startup.homepage
> - extensions.BabylonToolbar_i.newTabUrl
>
> Or if you have nothing to lose,
>   simply click **HELP > Troubleshooting** information and reset Firefox back
>   to the default.

You may also check [this link](http://info.delta-search.com/uninstall/firefox.html) from their page

Comment: How to reset the preferences.....
I mean from where do i reset the preferences.

Comment: You go to a new tab and write in the address bar `about:config`. Then you search for those preferences, right click and reset.

Comment: Yeaa i got that....
Thanxxxx a lot man this post of yours literally helped me a lot.